# Don't understand extra padding when using FrameLayout inside TableLayout

Tags: android

I'm trying to learn how to write Android programs, and I'm having trouble figuring out how padding works, in particular in a `FrameLayout` within a `TableLayout`.

```
private void fillTable(int nrows, int ncols) {
    final int CENTER = 0x11;  // used for "gravity" parameters
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.tablelayout);
    int counter = 1;
    TextView text;
    for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        table.addView(row);
        for (int j = 0; j < ncols; j++) {
            View cell;
            text = new TextView(this);
            text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            text.setText(Integer.toString(counter++));
            text.setGravity(CENTER);
            if (i == 2 && j == 2) {
                FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(this);
                text.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(90, 45, CENTER));
                frame.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                frame.addView(text);
                cell = frame;
            } else {
                cell = text;
            }
            cell.setBackgroundColor((i + j) % 2 == 0 ? Color.YELLOW : Color.WHITE);
            row.addView(cell);
            cell.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1F/ncols));
        }
        row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1F/nrows));
    }
}
```

`tablelayout` just looks like this:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tablelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</TableLayout>
```

I'm calling this with `nrows`=12 and `ncols`=5.  I'm running on an emulator whose width is 720 pixels.  If I change `if (i==2&&j==2)` to `if (false)`, so that only an array of `TextView` is displayed, the columns are even, as I expect.  However, with the code as written, the middle column is wider than the others.

I've also tried this adding `android:stretchColumns="*"` to the `tablelayout` definition and removing the weight parameter from `cell.setLayoutParams`, and the results are the same.

Assuming I have a reason to want to specify pixels for `text.setLayoutParams` (because of what I plan to do later), how would I get the column widths to be the same?  Since 90*5 is well under 720, I don't understand why, or where, the extra width is being added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you are dealing with weights, you must let the option take care of the remaining space. In this case **width**. Just set the width of each element to 0:

```
cell.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1F/ncols));
```

Comment: OK, that seems to work.  Thanks!  I think I misinterpreted some of the documentation of `TableLayout` and/or `TableRow`.

Comment: You did not seem to be convinced. Here's a quick explanation from LinearLayout. I believe the same applies to any layouts that implement it:
"To create a linear layout in which each child uses the same amount of space on the screen, set the android:layout_height of each view to "0dp" (for a vertical layout) or the android:layout_width of each view to "0dp" (for a horizontal layout). Then set the android:layout_weight of each view to "1"."
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight